# Simple HTML DOM parser acting slow

Tags: php, html, dom

Basically, what I am doing is this:

1. Getting the first 10 players/names in that list by evens: http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Aurora
2. Get the most recent death information from each of the players (here is an example player: http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Aaploo)
3. Print the dates of the most recent deaths.

I'm using the Simple HTML Dom for PHP.

My problem is that it is taking 7 seconds to load the results onto my page for 10 names.  This list has usually 1000 names over the course of a day.  That means it could take 15 minutes total for the whole entire list to be processed.  *Is this what it is?  Or can it be reduced?*

Here is an example snapshot of a result:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$start_time = microtime(true);


$html = file_get_html('http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Aurora');
$table = $html->find('table[class=Table2]');
$table = $table[0];

    $a2 = $table->find('tr[class=Even]');
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $a = $a2[$i];
    $player = $a->find('a');
    $player = $player[0];
    echo $player->href . '<br>';
    $html2 = file_get_html($player->href);
    $date = $html2->find('[@id="characters"]/div[5]/div/div/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]');
    $date = $date[0];
    echo "Most recent death date: " . $date . '<br>';
    $dateArr = explode(" ", $date);
    $dateArr = $dateArr[0];
    echo sizeof($dateArr) . '<br>';
    //for ($k = 0; count($dateArr[0]); $k++)
    //{
    //  echo $dateArr[0][$k] . '<br>';
    //}
}

echo "<br><br>This page was generated in " . (number_format(microtime(true) - $start_time, 2)) ." seconds.";

?>
```

EDIT / NEW way as recommended by cHao:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Aurora');
$html2 = file_get_contents('http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Aarkanito');
$dom = new domDocument;
$xpath = new domXpath($dom);
$dom->loadHTML($html2);

$a2 = $xpath->query('[@id="characters"]/div[5]/div/div/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]');
$a2 = $a2[0];

echo "Latest death: " . $a2;
```

Comment: simple_html_dom is slow as hell anyway.  That's what happens when you do all your parsing with pure PHP.  If you want speed, try DOMDocument and DOMXPath.  They use native code (libxml) to do the parsing, and will work with any HTML that's not boneheadedly mangled.

Comment: Also doesn't help much that you're grabbing a page for each game character, particularly with simple_html_dom parsing it.

Comment: Alright, so I made an edit to the original post with a new quick sample code at the bottom using DOMDocument and DOMXPath.  I know it doesn't work right now, but that's what I have at the moment.  If there anything that I may be doing incorrectly, please let me know.

Comment: (1) Your expression is not quite right.  Each step of the expression needs a node test (either an element name, or `text()`, etc).  And the expression should start with `//` unless you're testing the root specifically.  So prepend `//div` onto that expression.  (2) Node lists aren't arrays, and elements aren't strings.  Get the date item by saying `$a2 = $a2->item(0)->textContent;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch a lot of pages, maybe not now, but since you were asking about the whole list. I just tried it on my site and It took: 0.75 s to load the main page and an average of 0.23 s for each player page. So if you want to download every stat it should take you about less then 4 minutes.

Usually when i had to scrape a page and the scraping was taking a lot i would have used the google cache but the results from tibia.com are even better of google cache one's (about 0.3 s). However even if you wanted, you couldn't use google cache because it doesn't work with the method GET, so you can't send parametres.

There's not a real way to speed up the process since, remember, you want to scrape more then  1K of pages at once. If I was you I would be scared instead of being banned. Something very probable if you keep doing what you are doing. Are you really sure you need so much informations?

Comment: Scraping is illegal? I had no idea.  Thanks for letting me know :o

Comment: It's not illegal, but most sites don't like it much.  Check the TOS and see whether they say you're not allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to save locally the html and then write another script that scrapes the information. This way you can always modify, optimize, fetch more info with your parsing script at a later point in time.